# Javascript decision statements are not working properly

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a web form that is supposed to take in user input. The marital form asks the user if they are currently married and if they answer "yes" then another drop down type of question is suppose to appear underneath asking "how many times how you been married?" and so on and so forth. I created the decisions statements, but when I tested the marital form and put in "yes" nothing additional popped up.

The expected outcome is that when the user answers "yes" another question it is supposed to appear underneath.

Marital.php

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
      <style>
    .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
    /* Links inside the navbar */

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<head>

</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center;">
        <img src="../Images/CBH Logo 200px.png" alt="CBH Logo" height="80" width="80">
    </div>
    <h2>Johnson Behavioral Health Mental Evaluation Intake Application</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a>Education History</a>
        <a class="active" href="Marital.php">Marital History</a>
        <a>Employment History</a>
        <a>Military History</a>
        <a>Substances History</a>
        <a>Social/Personal History</a>
        <a>Physical Health History</a>
        <a>Mental Health History</a>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" id="marital_form" onsubmit="SetSectionComplete('marital')">

        <br></br>
        <table style="margin:0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <td class="Question">
                    Are you currently married?
                </td>
                <td style="width:100px;">
                    <select type="text" id="married" name="married" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital" required>
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                        <option value='No'>No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display:none" id="evermarried_row">
                <td>
                    Have you ever been married?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" id="evermarried" name="evermarried" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital">
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                        <option value='No'>No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display:none" id="howmanymarriages_row">
                <td>
                    How many times have you been married?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" id="howmanymarriages" name="howmanymarriages" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital">
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='1'>1</option>
                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                        <option value='4'>4</option>
                        <option value='5 or more'>5 or more</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display:none" id="divorced_row">
                <td>
                    Have you ever been divorced?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" id="divorced" name="divorced" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital">
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                        <option value='No'>No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display:none" id="widowed_row">
                <td>
                    Are you widowed?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" id="widowed" name="widowed" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital">
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                        <option value='No'>No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display:none" id="children_row" required>
                <td>
                    Do you have any children?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" id="children" name="children" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital">
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
                        <option value='No'>No</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display:none" id="howmanychildren_row">
                <td>
                    How many children do you have?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select type="text" id="howmanychildren" name="howmanychildren" style="width:100%;" class="needs_saved_marital">
                        <option value=''></option>
                        <option value='1'>1</option>
                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                        <option value='4'>4</option>
                        <option value='5'>5</option>
                        <option value='6'>6</option>
                        <option value='7 or more'>7 or more</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <table style="margin:0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <td><button class="reset_button" type="reset" value="Reset" id="marital_reset">Clear Marital</button></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Back!" onclick="history.back()"></td>
                <td><button class="save_button" formaction="Employment.php" id="marital_save" name="marital_save" value="Submit">Next</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Marital.js">
        function Marital_Validation() {
            $('#marital_save').css('border-color', '#163c6a');
            $('#marital_save').css('background', 'none');
            $('#marital_save').css('background-color', 'green');
            $('#marital_save').css('color', 'white');
            $('#marital_save').text('Saved');
            $('#marital_indicator').css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Marital.js

```
/*
 Marital variables:

married
evermarried
howmanymarriages
divorced  
widowed  
children
howmanychildren

*/

$(function(){

    $("#married").change(function(){
        var option=$("#married").val();
        if (option==='No'){
            $("#evermarried_row").show();
        }
        if (option==='Yes'){
            $("#howmanymarriages_row").show();
        }
    });

    $("#evermarried").change(function(){
        var option=$("#evermarried").val();
        if (option==='No'){
            $("#children_row").show();
            $("#howmanymarriages_row").hide();
        }
        if (option==='Yes'){
            $("#howmanymarriages_row").show();
        }
    });

    $("#howmanymarriages").change(function(){
        var option=$("#howmanymarriages").val();
        var married=$("#married").val();
        if (option==='1'){
            if (married==='Yes'){
                $("#children_row").show();
                $('#divorced_row').hide();
                $("#widowed_row").hide();
            }
            if (married==='No'){
                $('#divorced_row').show();
            }
        }
        if (option==='2' || option==='3' || option==='4' || option==='5 or more'){
            $('#divorced_row').show();

        }
    });

    $("#divorced").change(function(){
        var option=$("#divorced").val();
        var married=$("#married").val();
        var timesmarried=$("#howmanymarriages").val();
        if (option==='No'){
            $("#widowed_row").show();

        }
        if (option==='Yes'){
            if (timesmarried==='1'){
                $("#widowed_row").hide();
                $("#children_row").show();
            }
            if (timesmarried==='2' || timesmarried==='3' || timesmarried==='4' || timesmarried==='5 or more'){
                $("#widowed_row").show();

            }
        }
    });

    $("#widowed").change(function(){
        $("#children_row").show();
    });

    $("#children").change(function(){
        var option=$("#children").val();
        if (option==='No'){
            $("#howmanychildren_row").hide();
        }
        if (option==='Yes'){
            $("#howmanychildren_row").show();
        }
    });

    $(".needs_saved_marital").change(function(){
        var married=$("#married").val();
        var evermarried=$("#evermarried").val();
        var howmanymarriages=$("#howmanymarriages").val();
        var divorced=$("#divorced").val();
        var widowed=$("#widowed").val();  
        var children=$("#children").val();
        var howmanychildren=$("#howmanychildren").val();

        if (married==='Yes'){
            $("#evermarried").attr('required',false);
            $("#divorced").attr('required',false);
            $("#widowed").attr('required',false);
            $("#howmanymarriages").attr('required',true);
        }
        if (married==='No'){
            $("#divorced").attr('required',false);
            $("#widowed").attr('required',false);
            $("#evermarried").attr('required',true);
        }

        if (evermarried==='Yes'){
            $("#howmanymarriages").attr('required',true);
            $("#divorced").attr('required',true);
            $("#widowed").attr('required',true);
        }
        if (evermarried==='No'){
            $("#divorced").attr('required',false);
            $("#widowed").attr('required',false);
            $("#children").attr('required',true);
        }

        if (howmanymarriages==='2' || howmanymarriages==='3' || howmanymarriages==='4' || howmanymarriages==='5 or more'){
            $("#divorced").attr('required',true);
            $("#widowed").attr('required',true);
        }

        if (children==='Yes'){
            $("#howmanychildren").attr('required',true);
        }
        if (children==='No'){
            $("#howmanychildren").attr('required',false);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you include Marital.js anywhere not shown in your Marital.php code? Currently I don't see the script being included in your example.

Comment: Any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @smashed-potatoes, Marital.js is not included anywhere else that is not shown in my Marital.php. Awhile back the questions were working properly, but not are not so now I am stuck trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: In that case you are likely missing a script tag somewhere to include your javascript, e.g. something like this the head of your page: `<script src="Marital.js"></script>`

Comment: @Phil - The only error I get in my console is when I click the "Next" button the Marital.php: SetSectionComplete is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected. Checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ax6kfjvz/

I'm guessing you're including jQuery **after** your script. Or you're not including jQuery at all. Try this template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Couples Issues</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/your-awesome-script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When using a library, you must include them before your script otherwise the browser has no idea where let's say this function `$()` is coming from.

[Here is a good article.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-jquery)

Comment: Hi @mamady. I do not have jQuery after my script. I tried including the ajax code like was described but the other questions still do not appear. Furthermore, I got console error: “http://localhost/CBHApplication/Intake/Marital.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.[Learn More] Marital.php
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/CBHApplication/Intake/Marital.js” I updated my code for Marital.php in the original post.               Now I am confused as to why it is working in jsfiddle but not in Firefox.

Comment: That error sounds like you aren't getting your javascript back but instead html (likely an error) when the browser tries to load `localhost/CBHApplication/Intake/Marital.js`. Is that the correct path for your JS file? What do you get when you try to load that URL directly in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should trim the strings to avoid unmatched error and better use css visibility hidden!

```
 // like this
 var option=$("#married").val().trim();

 // like this
 <tr style="visibility: hidden;" ></tr>
```

Comment: OP's `<option>` values (eg `value='Yes'`) do not contain any whitespace so it's unlikely to be the problem